# Oulook Interop: Check if Account is default

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I use Outlook Interop to iterate over all accounts:

```
var app = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace _sessionNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

foreach (Account account in _sessionNs.Accounts)
{
    if (account != null)
    {
        var addressAccount = account.SmtpAddress;
        //TODO How to check if is default?
    }
}
```

I did not find any property or so on the Account object to check if it is the default account. 
I try with compare account.Session.CurrentProfileName to the app.DefaultProfile but that is the default Profile, and I want this for the same Profile with diffrent accounts. Also I tryed by GetDefaultFolder(FolderType:OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) but that did not change if I change the default in outlook.

Any idears?

Answer (score -1):

Create a new message programmatically and get its SendUsingAccount property. This is the default account.

Comment: If I use "var mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem) as MailItem" then "mailItem.Sender" is null. so this does not work.